# how do i display information in .aspx page using gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I am new to C# and have no idea how to display using C# gridview and display in my .aspx page. How do u code it? Below is the code i did, but i need some advice how whether its right.

here's my code in .aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="WorkshopEnrolled" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID"
DataSourceID="WorkshopEnrolledDataSource" EnableViewState="False">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopCode" HeaderText="Workshop Code"
      SortExpression="WorkshopCode" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopName" HeaderText="Workshop Name"
        HtmlEncode="False" SortExpression="WorkshopName">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopDate"
     HeaderText="Workshop Date" SortExpression="WorkshopDate">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkshopLocation"
       HeaderText="Workshop Location" SortExpression="WorkshopLocation">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
```

here's my .aspx.cs file

```
public partial class Workshop : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      HttpCookie httpCookie = Request.Cookies["TeamAwesomeCookie"];

      if (httpCookie != null)
      {
          // Write code to update photo filename in Users' table
          WorkshopController wc = new WorkshopController();
          ArrayList workshopEnrolled = wc.retrieveWorkshopByStudent(int.Parse(httpCookie.Values["UserID"]));
          ArrayList availableWorkshop = wc.retrieveAvailableWorkshops();

      }

    }


    protected void WorkshopEnrolled_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //string workshopCode = null;
       // string workshopName = null;
       // string workshopDate = null;
       // string workshopLocation = null;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Reference the ProductsRow via the e.Row.DataItem property
            Workshop workshopEnrolled = (Workshop)e.Row.DataItem;


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Where is the code for the WorkshopEnrolledDataSource?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance your code looks good except that you are forgetting to DataBind your grid and it seems that your intention is to bind the data from code behind. With that said, remove

```
 DataSourceID="WorkshopEnrolledDataSource"
```

From the markup and add these lines in code behind, below the 2 ArrayList declarations:

```
 WorkshopEnrolled.DataSource=          workshopEnrolled ;
 WorkshopEnrolled.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479339.aspx) I found via Google which has some useful walk-throughs for implementing a GridView.